# How to detect this dotted lines?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to identify the areas of the rooms on this plan. All rooms are circled in dotted lines. How can I define these dotted areas and get their coordinates relative to the image?

[image]

Red dots, I showed the coordinates of the corners of the rooms that I want to find. The search for rooms and coordinates interests me only by the dotted lines that are already on the original diagram. Black, I showed their location in one of the rooms.

I also tried to detect this lines with HAAR method, but I think it was a bad idea))

[image]

I will be very grateful if you can help. But I want to clarify that I am not interested in the method of finding these points through the intersection of the lines of the walls. I tried, it turns out terrible. the program works with an accuracy of 30%, as the walls are different. I want to do this through those dotted lines in the image.

Comment: Why not use the yellow background of the rooms in combination with the red dots?

Comment: Post the original image (without red dots and any other modifications)

Comment: Yes, @FrankMartin, segmenting yellow background seems to be more feasible.